# Magento 2 Custom Module Controller getLayout , createBlock, getBlock , append Fatal error:

Tags: layout, template, magento2.2.2, custom-block

```
 namespace My\Module\Controller\Index;

 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock(
        '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template',
        'my.block',
        array('template' => 'My_Module/test.phtml')
    )->toHtml();


    if($resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content')){
        $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content')
            ->append($block);
    }

    return $resultPage;
  }
}
```

The code above in controller returns :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function append() on boolean...
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: What you want to do actually?

Comment: Please share the full code of  controller

Answer (score 0):

As per as, your share code  seems only issue

```
$resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content.bottom')
```

Maybe  `content.bottom` the section is not rendered this page and you have try to append another block from  on non-exits section.

So, changes `$resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content.bottom')` with `$resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content')` and check what happen?

OR

**add this  below condition**

```
if($resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content.bottom')){
    $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content.bottom')
     ->append($block);
} 

    return $resultPage
```

**Instead of**

```
$resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content.bottom')
     ->append($block);
    return $resultPage;
```

Comment: ♦ That isn't not falling into the if  doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/180345/77554

Same issue answered - You're creating a new $resultPage from a factory and it is empty or null